# Release NSMutableDictionary memory under ARC in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In my app, I used the NSMutableDictionary and when I go to a specific view controller, the memory utilized increases more.

How can I free the used memory in Objective-C?

Comment: set it to nil and the memory is released

Comment: also note, if you are looking at the xcode memory usage thing when your app runs, what it shows is cumulative memory usage and not your current memory usage, if you want to see if you are leaking memory, use the instruments -> leaks tool

Comment: @Fonix In instruments,yellow color lines means what.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is assign it to `nil`. Under ARC that's all that's needed to 'release' an object:

```
self.myMutableDictionary = nil; //It no longer exists.
```

Note that this kills the reference that the view controller this code is run from has - if this is the only strong reference, then the object will be removed and the memory freed. If another object(s) have strong reference(s) pointing to the dictionary, though, then the memory won't be freed until those references are *also* set to nil. It's the responsibility of the allocating objects to be responsible and set their references to nil when they no longer need the object.

Comment: A bit simplistic. You set the reference to nil, that means that if nothing else has a strong reference to the dictionary then it will have `release` called on it, which will then call `release` on everything it contains, and as long as they have no strong references, they will be deallocated. Just setting it to nil is not enough if something else has a strong reference to it.

Comment: @Abizern Yes, but if something else has a strong reference to it it's quite safe to assume that that something probably needs access to the object. Thus it's that object's responsibility to deallocate it when it's done with it.

Comment: I'm not disputing your answer, just saying that setting it to `nil` does not, in itself, mean the object goes away. If the OP has a reference to it elsewhere that is strong when it doesn't need to be, that could also be a source of memory problems.